# Succinct contract state/storage root of a smart contract

Tags: contract-design, state-trie

In the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), it is mentioned(at section 4.1) that

> **storageRoot:** A 256-bit hash of the root node of a Merkle Patricia tree that encodes the storage contents of the account (a mapping between 256-bit integer values), encoded into the trie as a mapping from the Keccak 256-bit hash of the 256-bit integer keys to the RLP-encoded 256-bit integer values. The hash is formally denoted σ[a]_s.

Now

> I am using geth client and need to find σ[a]_s for a particular contract a. What could be a potential way to achieve that?

Additionally

> How to get account state σ [a] for a contract a.

Observe that I am only interested in the final succinct state of a contract which could be hash of the complete state of a contract at a particular instant of time and not the whole contract state which might include the code, storage etc.

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong, but there is no way to do it via web3. You'll have to lookup the contract address in the trie directly.